# Kafka connect jdbc oracle source numeric

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I am trying use Kafka-connect-jdbc to load data in incremental mode using query. Data is getting loaded to the topic. Key column to converted to Numeric(38,0) but it's getting truncated in the topic. I am suspecting that some conversion is happening. Its starts from 0 to 127 and then each digit is getting repeated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add more details as to how the key looks like in the topic.
As far as Confluent JDBC Source connector goes, there have been problems mapping the precision appropriately.

This [blog](https://rmoff.net/2018/05/21/kafka-connect-and-oracle-data-types/) sheds more light into the specifics of Oracle numeric type with respect to Kafka Connect.

Based on the problem description, I can suggest using the below property in the source property file:

```
numeric.mapping=best_fit
```

Comment: I am using confluent 3.2.2  so the numeric.mapping property is not available. The field is populated as  "FISCAL_WEEK_KEY":{"bytes":"\u0003\u001C"} in the topic.

Comment: Yes. Confluent 3.2.2 will not have the support for the NUMBER data type in Oracle. 
The data that is being shown in the topic is the byte stream, as Connect is unable to convert it to a corresponding data type.

Comment: Thanks for the Info Kumarjit, so my only option is to upgrade to latest confluent version?

Comment: Yes, Kafka Connect 4+ should give you those features.

Comment: I have used the new connector and it's working fine with the above property.  Thanks for the help.